# $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you prove that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}=1,$$ where $h \in \mathbb{C}$?

The identity is known to me in the real case, but how do you proceed in the complex case?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $\exp(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}?

Comment: By convention $h$ has no imaginary part, so saying it is complex is redundant.

Comment: @selfawareuser What do you mean saying "by convention $h$ has no imaginary part"? Do you suggest it makes no sense taking the limit for complex $h$? Or that it suffices to examine the case $h$ real? Both ways, this is wrong.

Comment: @C.Falcon Why is the latter wrong?

Comment: Consider $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{\textrm{Re}(z)}{z}$ as $z\to 0$. If $z$ stays real, $f(z)$ goes to 1. But if $z$ is allowed to take complex value, then $f(z)$ has no limit, as $f(iz)=0\neq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is still just the definition of the derivative of $e^z$ at $z=0$, which you know is $e^z|_0=1$. If you need to justify that the derivative of the exponential is indeed itself, you can note that it is analytic on the complex plane and differentiate the power series representation term-wise.

Answer (score 1):

If the limit is true we have that for any $\epsilon>0$ exists some $\delta>0$ such that

$$|z|<\delta\implies \left|\frac{e^z-1}{z}-1\right|<\epsilon$$

Then observe that for $|z|<1$ we have

$$\left|\frac{e^z-1}{z}-1\right|=\left|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!}}{z}-1\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{(k+1)!}-1\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{z^k}{(k+1)!}\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty |z|^k=\frac{|z|}{1-|z|} $$

and it is easy to see that $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{|z|}{1-|z|}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let define $f(x,y)=(e^x\cos(y),e^x\sin(y))$, it is clear that: $$\mathrm{d}_{(x,y)}f=\begin{pmatrix}e^x\cos(y)&e^x\sin(y)\\-e^x\sin(y)&e^x\cos(y)\end{pmatrix}.$$
By definition, one has $\|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-\mathrm{d}_{(0,0)}f(x,y)\|=o(\|(x,y)\|)$, which implies that: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\|f(x,y)-(1,0)\|}{\|(x,y)\|}=1.$$
Identifying $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ and noticing that $f(x,y)=\exp(z)$, the result should now be clear.